# How to send email with PHP?

Tags: php

[image]

I want to send an email using PHP. I've tried the code on the image but it won't send anything.
Is there any requirements that I haven't use or download yet? or is there any syntax mistake?

Comment: Please post code as plain text, not images.

Comment: Check your SMTP settings in `php.ini`, make sure they match the configuration of your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sending mail from you local machine than you need to have SMTP or Sendmail set into you local machine.